# Weierstrass $M$-Test Example

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does the power series about $0$ for $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ converge
>   uniformly for $x \in (0,1)$?

I am trying to use the Weierstrass $M$-Test. 
This is what I have so far:

$\frac{1}{x^2+1} = \frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}= 1+(-x^2)+(-x^2)^2+\ldots = 1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\ldots = \Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}(-x^2)^{k-1}$

Let the last series be my $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}g_k(x)$. 
Now does there exist $M_k$ such that $\lVert g_k(x) \rVert \leq M_k$ for all $x \in (0,1)$, where $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} M_k$ converges?

Comment: The $M_k$ must be positive, so your last line makes no sense.

Comment: Also, please clarify the question. It is not the convergence of $1/(1+x^2)$ that concerns you (that does not mean anything). You seem to be asking about the convergence of the power series of $1/(1+x^2)$ about $0$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I was not aware that $M_k$ must be positive. Yes, I do mean the convergence of the power series about 0. I will make sure to clarify.

Comment: $0< \|g_k\|$, right? So, if $\|g_k\|\le M_k$, then the $M_k$ must be positive.

Answer (score 1):

The [Weierstrass $M$-Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) isn't going to get the job done (at least as is,  with this function on this interval) since $M_n=1$ here. But it doesn't sound like you were forced to use the $M$-Test. Instead, just compute the uniform error straightaway (leveraging the fact that you are working with a geometric series):
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in(0,1)}\left|\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^nx^{2n}}_{N\text{th partial sum}}-{1\over 1+x^2}\right|
&=\sup_{x\in(0,1)}\left|{1-(-x^2)^{N+1}\over 1-(-x^2)}-{1\over 1+x^2}\right|\\
&=\sup_{x\in(0,1)}\left|(-1)^Nx^{2N+2}\over 1+x^2\right|\\
&=\sup_{x\in(0,1)}{x^{2N+2}\over 1+x^2}\\
&={1\over 2}\not\to 0\text{ as }N\to\infty.
\end{align}
So $\displaystyle f_N(x):=\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^nx^{2n}$ does *not* converge uniformly on $0<x<1$. (Note that if instead your interval was, say, $0<x<1-\varepsilon$, then both Weierstrass and this other method would work to establish uniform convergence.)